# Piranha module development template

Tags: c#, piranha-cms

Is there a template that can be used to develop custom Piranha CMS modules? If it's possible is there a way to integrate the module with the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Piranha CMS doesn't contain a **module** features with Init, Install and so on. Building a module in the current version is more or packaging everything into a dll and using WebActivatorEx together with the framework hooks to register your code.

You can for example take a look at the localization module and how it registers its events.

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha.Localization

Use this as a reference and then just submit issues/feature requests on what support you would need for your module at the GitHub repo!

Regards

Håkan

---

**UPDATE**

This answer is over four years old and the link points to an example project that doesn't exist anymore for the old legacy version of Piranha CMS. The example was created for someone else to take over, but after three years without activity we decided to delete it.

If you are in fact interested in module development for the new .NET Core version of Piranha CMS this information will be available in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot...will look at the Piranha.Localization example and see if I can follow the structure and produce my own custom module

Comment: Great! If you run into something on the way that should be exposed in the core framework just let me know and I'll try to fix it!

Comment: Piranha is a great CMS, am enjoying it..makes it easy to build what you want inside a CMS..Good Job Hakan

Comment: Hi there @Jan'splite'K. This answer is four years old and point to an example for the legacy version of Piranha CMS. We put it online for someone else to take over but when no one had shown interest in it for three years, and we got questions on why it wasn't complete or updated, we simple deleted it. I'll make sure I'll update the answer to reflect this. 

Regards

Comment: Hi, @HåkanEdling - yeah, i am trying to find how to get my custom module somehow managed by Piranha.Manager, so i come across this question (is top in google results for me :) ). So your updated answer is really welcomed, thanks :)

Comment: If you want to take a look at a typical module, take a look at the Piranha.AspNetCore.Identity project in the main Piranha.Core repo at GitHub. It adds itself as a Module and extends the Manager Menu with new views & controllers.